# In what scripts the oldest Sanskrit literature was written?

Tags: scripture, sanskrit

In what scripts the oldest Sanskrit literature was written? When was Brahmi script used for it? I am aware that Vedas were orally memorized -- and were not written for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Manuscripts also count then:

***1. [Bakhshali manuscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bakhshali_manuscript)***

The Bakhshali manuscript is variously dated between 3rd century (acc. to carbon dating methods) to 9th century AD, and it was found in in the Gandhāra region. It was a mathematical text written **Śāradā script** (suitable for being found in Gandhāra).

***2. [Bower Manuscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bower_Manuscript)***

The Bower manuscript is dated to around the 5th-6th century AD. It was a text regarding Buddhism and Ayurveda mainly. It was found in northwestern China. It is not in pure Sanskrit but a type of mixed-Sanskrit called Hybrid Sanskrit. It was written in **Gupta script** (a form of **Brahmi script**).

***3. [Spitzer Manuscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spitzer_Manuscript)***

Arguably the oldest Sanskrit Manuscript. It's carbon dated to the 2nd century AD. It contains a treatise on Nyaya-Vaiśeṣika but it is more popular for containing a summary of the Parvas of the Mahābhārata. It was written in **Brahmi script**.

Comment: Does it mean that Brahmi script, at its inception during the time of King Ashok, was used for Pali and not Sanskrit?

Comment: @UdghoshYt We're not sure for certain but the first inscriptions in Brahmi were in prakrit.